# How to correctly pass extra properties to clientContext.load function

Tags: client-object-model

I have created a generic function which returns a list with only selected properties as shown:

```
var getList = function (listTitle, properties) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);   
        // This works properly
        //clientContext.load(list, 'DefaultEditFormUrl', 'DefaultNewFormUrl', 'Id');        

        clientContext.load(list, properties);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this,
                function () { deferred.resolve(list); }),
            Function.createDelegate(this,
                function (sender, args) { deferred.reject(sender, args); }));

        return deferred.promise();
    };
```

The issue is how to call this function properly. The below call only loads `'DefaultEditFormUrl'`.

```
var ListTitle = 'myListTitle';
getList(ListTitle, 'DefaultEditFormUrl', 'DefaultNewFormUrl', 'Id')
```

And the below call gives error:

> The query expression is not supported

```
var ListTitle = 'myListTitle';
getList(ListTitle, 'DefaultEditFormUrl\', \'DefaultNewFormUrl\', \'Id')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `SP.ClientRuntimeContext.prototype.load(clientObject) method` accepts properties as *dynamic parameters*, you could consider the following approach:

```
var getList = function (listTitle) {
     var deferred = $.Deferred();
     var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
     var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);   

     //construct arguments for SP.ClientRuntimeContext.prototype.load method
     var loadArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
     loadArgs.splice(0, 1);  //remove first arg since it is a List Title
     loadArgs.unshift(list); //insert ClientObject as first arg 
     SP.ClientRuntimeContext.prototype.load.apply(ctx,loadArgs);
     ctx.executeQueryAsync(
            function () { 
               deferred.resolve(list);
            },
            function (sender, args) { 
               deferred.reject(sender, args); 
            });
     return deferred.promise();       
};
```

Usage

```
getList('Documents', 'DefaultNewFormUrl','DefaultEditFormUrl','Id')
.done(function(list)
{
   console.log(list.get_defaultEditFormUrl());
   console.log(list.get_defaultNewFormUrl());
   console.log(list.get_id().toString());
})
.fail(
function(sender,args){
    console.log(args.get_message());
});
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the help. That works perfectly.

Comment: Given the title of the question, I think it would be useful to add that if you're loading a collection of items (instead of a single object like a list) you need to use the "Include(Field1, Field2, Field3)" argument syntax instead of seperate string arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add that you could pass the properties as an array, if you look at the definition for the load function:

```
load: function SP_ClientRuntimeContext$load(clientObject) {
        if (!clientObject) {
            throw Error.argumentNull('clientObject');
        }
        SP.ClientAction.$j(this, clientObject);
        var $v_0 = null;

        if (arguments.length === 2 && Array.isInstanceOfType(arguments[1])) {
            $v_0 = arguments[1];
        }
        else {
            var $v_1 = [];

            for (var $v_2 = 1; $v_2 < arguments.length; $v_2++) {
                Array.add($v_1, arguments[$v_2]);
            }
            $v_0 = $v_1;
        }
        SP.DataRetrievalWithExpressionString.load(clientObject, $v_0);
```

Then you use it like this:

```
getList(ListTitle, ['DefaultEditFormUrl', 'DefaultNewFormUrl', 'Id'])
```